# K8S Ingress controller redirect to the wrong path

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have an Nginx ingress controller running on one k8s namespace,
and on another k8s namespace, I defined a pod, a service, and an ingress resource.
this is the ingress resource definition:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-app-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  ingressClassName: general-internal
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: "/my-app(/|$)(.*)"
        backend:
          serviceName: my-app-svc
          servicePort: 443
```

now, when I access this link:

```
http://example.com/my-app/some-path/
```

then everything is ok because the "my-app-svc" knows the path "/some-path/" and returns a 200 response (the forwarding is to `http://my-app-svc/some-path` and that's great because my-app-svc doesn't and shouldn't know or care for the `/my-app` prefix that exists only for the nginx ingress controller so it will know to forward that request to "my-app-svc" internally).

but when I access this link (notice no "/" in the end):

```
http://example.com/my-app/some-path
```

I get a redirection response from the "my-app-svc" service, and the "Location" header contains "/some-path/", so the redirection is to:

```
http://example.com/some-path/
```

which does not lead to the "my-app-svc" service because it doesn't have the "/my-app" prefix.

If the Location header was "/my-app/some-path/" instead of "/some-path/" then everything was ok because the redirection would be to:

```
http://example.com/my-app/some-path/
```

which would give me the 200 response.

the question is, how can I do that the ingress controller will add a "my-app" prefix to the Location header when it returns the redirection response to the client?

Thanks

Comment: Hello @Ofir, if I can see correctly your 404 error looks like ingress behavior. Look at your rewrite target: `/$2`. That means you are capturing the second group of `- path: "/my-app(/|$)(.*)"`. Your second group would be `(.*)`. In your example, you'll capture only `some-path`. And this group will be appended to `http://example.com/`. So the expected result should be `http://example.com/some-path/`. If you want to direct requests to `http://example.com/my-app/some-path` try changing the rewrite target to `/my-app/$2`

Comment: Additionally, select [path type](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#path-types) to `Prefix`. You will be able to get to your application via the address with `/` at the end or without it. You can also remove `"` from `- path: "/my-app(/|$)(.*)"`. For more information you can read the [doc](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/#rewrite-target)

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak Hi, thanks for you answer, I edited my question so it will be clearer. please notice that `http://example.com/my-app/some-path/` forward to `http://my-app-svc/some-path/` internally inside the k8s, and that is intentionally. I use the "/my-app" prefix in order to make the nginx ingress to route the request to the "my-app-svc" internally, so I dont want to change the "/$2", I only want the nginx ingress controller to change the redirection response that "my-app-svc" returns to the client, by adding the "/my-app" prefix to the Loaction header...

Comment: I think you mixed up the URL with the site name: "`http://example.com/my-app/some-path/ ` forward to `http: // my-app-svc / some-path /`". 
Based on your configuration and [documentation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/#rewrite-target) `http://example.com/my-app/some-path/` should be rewrited (forwarded) to `http://example.com/some-path/`.  Could you attach some screenshots? If you want to add a `my-app` prefix to the location header, you really need to change `/$2`. Based on your configuration, it works as it should.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to my co-worker, we found a solution for the problem:

The solution is to add these annotations to the ingess resource:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-redirect-from: /
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-redirect-to: /my-app/
```

meaning:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-app-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-redirect-from: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-redirect-to: /my-app/
spec:
  ingressClassName: general-internal
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: "/my-app(/|$)(.*)"
        backend:
          serviceName: my-app-svc
          servicePort: 443
```

It seems that the annotations above check the "Location" header in the redirection response to the client, and replace the first `/` with `/my-app/` and only after this change - the redirection response is sent to the client.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone landing here and finding the above solution not working (like myself), you might be using nginx-based ingress https://www.nginx.com/blog/guide-to-choosing-ingress-controller-part-4-nginx-ingress-controller-options/ which needs different annotation to your ingress resource:

```
nginx.org/rewrites: "serviceName=service1 rewrite=rewrite1[;serviceName=service2 rewrite=rewrite2;...]"
```

which worked for me.

A complete declaration from https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/v2.3.0/examples/rewrites copied here:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1 
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: cafe-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.org/rewrites: "serviceName=tea-svc rewrite=/;serviceName=coffee-svc rewrite=/beans/"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: cafe.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /tea/
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: tea-svc
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /coffee/
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: coffee-svc
            port:
              number: 80
```